# ASP.NET MVC & Windows Phone integration with Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-phone-8, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an application that allows people to authenticate with the same credentials in both MVC and Windows Phone apps. Data access for the phone and MVC client should be via Web API (or alternatively via WCF).

I've already read dozens of articles on authorization frameworks and it gave me a headache as there's quite a few of them and I don't even know how to start.

So my questions are: how can I accomplish these goals? What authorization framework should I use?

Comment: you could take a look Asp.net Identity.

Comment: Hi, you can go with membership provider, is the one being use by default in the new ASP.NET MVC  project template, however I'm not a big fan of it too many [abstractions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PleaseLearnToThinkAboutAbstractions.aspx). Do you already have a DB model? In your place I will have a token based authentication and handle the MVC and WP app again the API. It you need any further question let me know.

Comment: Yes, I already have a DB model (why is it this relevant?). What do you mean by token basen authentication? Any frameworks or libraries?